# Get out every character that is not a letter or a number PHP

Tags: php, escaping, character, special-characters

I have a very simple string:

```
suhfdgfsdf6z87wrt348rfgrztf873$[{;÷[öw
```

and a very simple question:
How could I get out (exclude) every character that is not a letter or a number in PHP?

Comment: Do you count `ö` as a letter? (By the way, it *is* actually a letter.)

Comment: Yeah `ö` is a letter for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This clean also UTF letters.

```
$r = preg_replace('/[\pL\d]/u', '', $var);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// includes underscores
preg_replace('/[\w]+/', '', $var);
```

Or

```
preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '', $var);
```

After which you should be left with just your special characters.

Comment: \b is a word character which matches [a-zA-Z0-9_] so the \d is not needed but you need to still remove the underscore.

Comment: Oh that's right I forgot that it included _numbers_ already. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I tested it with \b and it didn't work as expected (I believe \b changes behavior when enclosed in brackets). I changed it to \w and that worked better.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = '!@#$%ABCDEFG1234567()*&';
echo ereg_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', $string)

?>
```

I see someone already has this, but they used preg_replace, which is better since ereg_replace will not be supported any longer.